# Node.js mongodb updateMany with index

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Is there any way so that I can use the current index or document number or cursor id in [updateMany](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.2/api/Collection.html#updateMany) method?

For example:

`db.collection("users").updateMany({}, { $set: {"uname": "user_" + $index}});`

Here the $index means the current number or index or serial of the document.

I am using [MongoDB Node.JS Driver 2.2](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.2/api)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way with [updateMany](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.2/api/Collection.html#updateMany) method to perform this kind of operations. However an efficient solution is to use [find](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.2/api/Collection.html#find) and [bulkWrite](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.2/api/Collection.html#bulkWrite) in combination.

Example (using function generators and yield):

```
var coll = db.collection("users");
var Users = yield coll.find().toArray();
var bulkArray = [];
Users.forEach(function* (d, i) {
    bulkArray.push({ updateOne: { filter: { _id: mongodb.ObjectID(d._id) }, 
        update: { $set: { uname: 'user_' + i }}, upsert:true });
});
yield coll.bulkWrite(bulkArray, {ordered:true, w:1});
```